# How to perform background sync task if I were using GoogleSignIn + DriveClient

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Our users have a chance to login, to authorize the app access to their Google Drive. We implement based on `GoogleSignIn` and `DriveClient`. (Not the yet another deprecated API `GoogleApiClient`)

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth

After the users quit the app, we would like to Google Drive sync process still work seamlessly in background, without further user/UI interaction. (Able to handle case when login token is expired/invalid after few days/hours)

May I know how to achieve so. Any code example is appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly then I think you can use WorkManager Once your app is authenticated .

Comment: Yes. I'm know about WorkManager but that is not my concern. My concern is after certain period (few hours later, few days later, ...) The previous sign in token can become invalid. How do we deal with such situation, without requires user to interaction with sign in UI again.

Comment: Ohkk . Well AFAIK you can only ask for a new token with user permission i.e UI . Keep digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`silentSignIn` is the key to the solution. We also need to handle edge case, when `silentSignIn` failed. Here's the real world code snippet.

---

```
public static GoogleSignInClient buildGoogleSignInClient() {
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
            new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                    .build();
    return GoogleSignIn.getClient(WeNoteApplication.instance(), signInOptions);
}

public static boolean silentSignInThenSync(SyncViewModel syncViewModel, boolean handleSignInRequired) {
    GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = buildGoogleSignInClient();

    Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = googleSignInClient.silentSignIn();

    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        syncViewModel.getSlientSignInSuccessLiveData().postValue(true);

        return sync(task.getResult(), syncViewModel);
    } else {

        try {
            Tasks.await(task);
            try {
                GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = task.getResult(ApiException.class);

                syncViewModel.getSlientSignInSuccessLiveData().postValue(true);

                return sync(googleSignInAccount, syncViewModel);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "", e);

                if (handleSignInRequired) {
                    if (e.getStatusCode() == GoogleSignInStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED) {
                        syncViewModel.getSignInRequiredLiveData().postValue(true);
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                String message = WeNoteApplication.instance().getString(R.string.sync_with_google_drive_failed_template, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                syncViewModel.getMessageLiveData().postValue(message);
            }
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e);

            if (handleSignInRequired) {
                if (e.getCause() instanceof ApiException) {
                    if (((ApiException) e.getCause()).getStatusCode() == GoogleSignInStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED) {
                        syncViewModel.getSignInRequiredLiveData().postValue(true);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            String message = WeNoteApplication.instance().getString(R.string.sync_with_google_drive_failed_template, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            syncViewModel.getMessageLiveData().postValue(message);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e);

            String message = WeNoteApplication.instance().getString(R.string.sync_with_google_drive_failed_template, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            syncViewModel.getMessageLiveData().postValue(message);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```